# React Native 'yarn run ios' doesn't initialize the project on M1

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, apple-m1, flipper

I'm a new user to Mac OS and its system and M1. Whenever I try `yarn run ios` command it's open normal simulator but not the project that I'm building and it throws me that error and error code 65:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening dealerApp.xcodeproj.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project dealerApp.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme dealerApp -destination id=0A358C3D-FE10-4872-9913-F927BCC93B29

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Using build description from disk
note: Build preparation complete
PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/bigez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dealerApp-cixnurkshkczahhihjqgcgbblssu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/dealerApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/dealerApp.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'dealerApp' from project 'dealerApp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually run `yarn ios`.

Also, you might try running the project with Xcode. It should give you a more useful error log so you can find out what the real problem is. Look for the red X icons and see what they say.